# SharePoint Designer Workflow create new item with lookup to current item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, lookup-column, workflow-lookup

I have two lists, "customers" and "expense Sheets". The list "expense sheets" has a lookup column "related customer" to the "title" field of the "customer" list. I am trying to create a workflow for the list "customers", which creates an "expense sheet" item, which has the lookup field filled with the current item in the "customers" list, from which I start the workflow. Unfortunately, this always creates an error.

Another field type in the "expense sheet" list would not work for me as I Need the special connection created by a lookup field.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: What is the error message ? What are you assigning as the value for the lookup ?

Comment: The error is:
"Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type."

Comment: the lookup in the list "expense sheet" refers to the field title in the list "customers".

Comment: in the workflow I try to use the value for the related customer: "current item: title"

Comment: Try the ID instead of the title.

Comment: Now the error changed to: "an error has occured in create expense sheet"... I also tried to edit the lookup column Settings to ID instead of title, but the error stays

Comment: And if you try with this format :  ID;#Title

Comment: Unfortunately I can only choose a fixed choice in Data Source "Current Item"

Comment: You need to set your lookup field in the workflow to Current Item:ID.

Comment: I did this, but it did not work. I have set the lookup column in the list to ID, and the workflow uses current item: ID to fill the lookup column